# how I get TargetFrameworkVersion v8.0?

Tags: c#, android, binding, visual-studio-2017

Project Textapp.android cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v8.0 because it s not supported. Please change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is supported.

Comment: Download it using the SDK Manager. Are you using xamarin? And which project does throw this error? I guess that occurs when building? Can you please add some more information?

Comment: An error occurred trying to load the page.
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: API level not recognized: 26

I have this error in Android Mainfest property page of project

Comment: Having same issue with TargetFrameworkVersion v8.1

**Project App.Droid cannot build using TargetFrameworkVersion v8.1 because it is not supported. Please change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is supported.**

Comment: For Android v8.0 you need Visual Studio 15.6 or higher.
With VS 15.8.x I had problems with Xamarin.Forms projects. The latest VS version I was able to use with Xamarin.Forms projects is 15.6.7
With the tater versions I had deployment issues. Had to downgrade (to v15.6.7) - what means uninstall VS and install the right version